# how to use methods and test case python

Tags: python, user-interface, methods

Hi new to object oriented programming how do I turn this into a method on python and test it in a main? not sure what the parameters should be. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

```
print("Before updating a record ")
sql_select_query = """select * from dash_requirementsMP2 where id = 1"""
cursor.execute(sql_select_query)
record = cursor.fetchone()
print(record)

# Update single record now
sql_update_query = """Update dash_requirementsMP2 set REQUESTER = 'Michael' where id = 1"""
cursor.execute(sql_update_query)
connection.commit()
print("Record Updated successfully ")

print("After updating record ")
cursor.execute(sql_select_query)
record = cursor.fetchone()
print(record)
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason of trying to put this into a class? I'm not an OOP developer, but I would think that the need should precede the want in a case like this.

Comment: yes I am trying to put it into a class so I can call the class in different files.

Comment: Does it need to be a method in a class or could it just be a plain function in the module?

Comment: just a plain function but I'm adding I plan on adding it to a class later on.

Comment: This is not enough code / background info to decide, if and where functions would make sense. If you call the above only once, then not, if you call all lines over and over, all is one function. Or it should be split, depending where you need just some of the lines. (Btw - I suggest to train structured programming with simpler tasks than DB access, direct usage of SQL strings will lead to possible SQL injections later on.)